# Exclude table from List of tables but keep numbering

Tags: tables, captions

I have a simple table which I would like to exclude from the list of tables (LOT). I found out this can be done via `\caption*`. But the problem is that this approach removes the numbering of the table. The only thing that is left is the caption. Can I keep the full caption, but not include the table in the LOT?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

    \listoftables

    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c} 
            0.999 \\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption*{This is my caption.}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: isn't your list of tables going to look very odd if it does not have consecutive numbering?

Comment: you could use `\caption` with `\renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}` immediately before it but that's so weird I don't think I want to post as an answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your comments. No basically this is supposed to be an additional part, added to a larger table. That's why I do not want to create a new table number, but rather have the same number as the previous table + some new caption. That's also why it does not make sense for me to have that as part of the List of tables. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: oh that's a completely different question look at \ContinuedFloat from the float package to make one table be consider part of a previous. see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34579/is-there-really-something-wrong-with-using-the-caption-package-for-continuedflo